# How to display file details (size, date, etc.) from Linux “locate” command?

Tags: linux, find, ls, locate

The (slow) Linux “find” command has an option, “-ls”, to display size, date, etc. like the “ls -l” command. But the “locate” command doesn’t seem to have that. So how can I get the equivalent functionality with locate?

I’ve used back-ticks to pass the output of locate to ls, like this:

```
ls -al `locate -e somefile`
```

…which works as long as somefile exists. But if somefile doesn’t exist, it gives me a full directory listing.

If I do this:

```
ls -al `locate -e somefile` thisfileneverexists
```

…then it sort of works, if you don’t mind the error line:

```
ls: cannot access thisfileneverexists: No such file or directory
```

…which leads us to the obvious-but-extremely-ugly workaround:

```
ls -al `locate -e somefile` thisfileneverexists 2>/dev/nul
```

That works, but surely there’s a better way!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `xargs`.  This takes as input a series of parameters, and carries out an operation on them:

```
 locate -eb0P somefile | xargs -r0 ls -ald
```

xargs will carry out the `ls -ald` command using the results of the locate as parameters.

The `-e` switch tells locate to check that files found in the database really exist, and ignore any which don't.

The `-b` switch tells locate to match just basenames.

The `-0` (zero) switch tells locate to generate null delimiters instead of blanks (so it can handle file names which contain blanks)

The `-P` switch tells locate to list broken symlinks

The `-r` switch tells xargs to not carry out the command if nothing is passed in - ie when the locate returns nothing.

The `-0` switch tells xargs to expect nulls instead of blanks as delimiters

The `-a` switch tells ls to list even files that begin with "."

The `-d` switch tells ls to list directories rather than their contents

Comment: Unfortunately, that breaks for files with blanks in the names, and also for directory names that match the pattern.  This works better:

"locate -eb0 somefile | xargs -r --null ls -ald"

The options mean:

locate
 -e = only match files that actually exist
 -b = match basename
 -0 = use null delimiters instead of spaces

xargs
 --null = expect null delimiters instead of spaces
 
ls
 -d = list directories rather than their contents
 -a = list even hidden files (with names which begin with ".")

Comment: +1: This is gold. It is the way I _want_ `locate` to work, since finding a file isn’t always enough — finding the date and size of a file will help to distinguish it from others.

Answer (score 3):

Store the result of `locate` in a variable, check to see if it has any value, and then view that.

```
f=`locate ...`
[ "$f" ] && ls -al "$f"
```

The reason you can't get this information from `locate` directly is because it's not in the database that `locate` uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop through the `locate` output:

```
locate somefile | while IFS= read -r i; do ls -la "$i"; done
```